# Making a Copy a Drag and Drop component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Currently I have two Boards and a card. I am able to drag the card from one to the other and vice versa

I am now trying  to make a copy of the card when I drag instead of moving the actual card over.

The Main board which stuff will be dragged to:

```js
<template>
    <div
        :id="id"
        class="board"
        @dragover.prevent
        @drop.prevent="drop"
    >
        <slot />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props:['id'],
    methods: {
        drop: e => {
            const card_id = e.dataTransfer.getData('card_id');

            const card = document.getElementById(card_id);

            card.style.display = "block"

            e.target.appendChild(card);
        }
    }
} 
</script>
```

The sideboard where I drag stuff from:

```js
<template>
    <div
        :id="id"
        class="test"
        @dragover.prevent
        @drop.prevent="drop"
    >
        <slot />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props:['id'],
    methods: {
        drop: e => {
            const card_id = e.dataTransfer.getData('card_id');

            const card = document.getElementById(card_id);

            card.style.display = "block"

            e.target.appendChild(card);
        }
    },
    data(){
        return{
            title:'test'
        }
    }
} 
</script>
```

The card:

```js
<template>
    <div 
        :id="id"
        class="card"
        :draggable="draggable"
        @dragstart="dragStart"
        @dragover.stop
    >
      <div class="test2">
          <i class="icon-text-width"></i>  Object
      </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default{
    props:['id','draggable'],
    methods: {
        dragStart: e => {
            const target = e.target;
            
            e.dataTransfer.setData('card_id', target.id)

            setTimeout(() => {
                target.style.display = "none";
            },0)
        }
    },
    data(){
        return{
            test:''
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style >
.test2{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}
</style>
```

the App.Vue

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
      <main class="flexbox">
          
        <Board id="board-1">
        
        </Board>
        <SideBoard id="board-2" class="test">
            <Card id="card-1" draggable='true'>
                <p>Object Card</p>
            </card>
        </SideBoard>


      </main>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Board from './components/Board.vue'
import Card from './components/Card.vue'
import SideBoard from './components/sideBoard.vue'


export default {
  name: 'App',
  data(){
      return{
         
      }
  },
  components: {
      Board,
      Card,
      SideBoard,

  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: can you create an online example, I think it can make your question clearly https://codesandbox.io/s/vue

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/drag-n-drop-45yx5

should work now I think.

Answer (score 0):

It looks in your CodeSandbox that when you drop a card in the sidebar or the board that you fire the function drop. In that function you have access to the card that is dragged.
If I where you I would emit the html element of that card to the app.vue and then place it in the board. Then the placement (append card in target) I would remove that part. So the card is always, and always present in the sidebar.